# displaying a table from views.py in a django project

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

```
<table class="table">
     <thead>
     <tr>
          <th>School</th>
          <th>Strength</th>
          <th>Average</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     {% for school in cluster.school_set.all %}
          <tr>
               <td><a href="{% url 'data:school_detail' state.id region.id cluster.id school.id %}">{{ school.school_name }}</a></td>
               <td>{{ school.strength }}</td>
               <td>school average</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the table in my template which shows details of all the schools in a cluster(town/city) in a tabular form with columns as 1) School Name 2) School strength 3) school Average Marks from certain number of exams.
I could easily get the data for columns 1) school name & 2) school strength because they are just fields for class School. The problem is with the column average. To get the average I need to have certain lines of code which I cannot do directly in template. The problem is I don't know how to do it in views.py either. to calculate that I need school.id but from url I only get cluster.id
What to do in these cases where you cannot simply get the data from views.py without giving a value from template?

```
set = Average.objects.filter(school=school.id):
obj = set.latest('average_date')
avg = obj.average_value
```

These are the lines of code I need to get the average of a particular school.

```
class School(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = ChainedForeignKey(Region, chained_field="state",chained_model_field="state", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cluster = ChainedForeignKey(Cluster, chained_field="region",chained_model_field="region", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    facilitator = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    f_number = models.IntegerField()
    f_email = models.EmailField()
    school_logo = models.FileField(default='')
    strength = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name


class Avergae(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = ChainedForeignKey(Region, chained_field="state",chained_model_field="state", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cluster = ChainedForeignKey(Cluster, chained_field="region",chained_model_field="region", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = ChainedForeignKey(School, chained_field="cluster",chained_model_field="cluster", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    average_date = models.DateField()
    average_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    average_attendance = models.IntegerField()
    average_note = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.average_date, self.average_value)
```

These are my models for School and Average

Comment: you can create method in the `school` model or create django custom filter, please show example of your `Average` calculation and school model, please

Comment: Yes, post the model and the view.

Comment: I just updated the question please have a look

Comment: @MadPhysicist also updated models. Please help me through this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `School` model you can write a method `get_average`:

```
class School(models.Model):
    # other fields
    def get_average(self):
        return self.avergae_set.latest('average_date').average_value
```

Then in template you could do:

```
{{ school.get_average }}
```

Note: Your Average model name spellings are wrong, you have `Avergae` instead it should be `Average`

Comment: school object has no attribute average_set is the error I'm getting.

Comment: Please copy the code again, I uses the `average` first instead of `avergae`, but later realised you have spelling mistake. So it should be `avergae_set` based on your code.

Comment: That's the last thing I ever wanted. My bad :p Thanq bro I have been stuck with this for a long time now.